# Dynamically add property sources to SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

Similar to [Springboot unit test set @Configuration Properties dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179362/springboot-unit-test-set-configuration-properties-dynamically) but the context is different.

In my case I have a [TestContainer](https://www.testcontainers.org/) running a custom MySQL database that is prepopulated with a lot of data (not using the SQL batch loading approach because the data is an anonymized copy of production and doing it through SQLs makes the boot up time of the container 20 minutes vs 2 minutes).

So far my test looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
        Bootstrap.class
    }
)
public class ITFakeDB {
    @ClassRule
    public static final GenericContainer DB = new GenericContainer("devdb")
        .withExposedPorts(3306);
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private Users users;

    @Test
    public void testDatabaseIsUp() {
        assertTrue(DB.getMappedPort(3306) != 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser() {
        Optional<User> user = users.findByLoginName("mimi");
        assertTrue(users.isPresent());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is somehow set the `spring.datasource.url` (or in my case `datasources.schema1.url` because I did the [routing datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196106/242042)) to the one used by `DB`

Comment: what's the method in `DB` that gets you the URL,  to set to the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually override the property from within your Spring-boot test by using `ContextConfiguration` and `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Override the property - define a static inner class:

```java
  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + DB.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + DB.getMappedPort(3306) + "/my_db";

      TestPropertyValues
          .of("datasources.schema1.url=" + url)
          .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
  }
```

Note: I have assumed that the `url` is derived from the ip address, port and db name. You may change that part as needed but the core idea remains.

`ApplicationContextInitializer` can be used for programmatically initializing a Spring context before context refresh. Now, wire up the context initializer class by annotating at test class level with `ContextConfiguration`:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = Initializer.class)
```

Docs:

[ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)

[ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html)

Comment: That doesn't work if datasources.schema1.url is already defined in .properties file

Answer (score 3):

While the previous answer should work, Spring Framework 5.2.5 (that is included into Spring Boot 2.2.6) has introduced a new `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation exactly for that case:

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void initializeDatasource(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    String ip    = DB.getContainerIpAddress();
    Integer port = DB.getMappedPort(3306);
    String url   = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/my_db", ip, port);
    
    registry.add("datasources.schema1.url", url);
}
```

See for details:

- Blog: [@DynamicPropertySource in Spring Framework 5.2.5 and Spring Boot 2.2.6](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6)
- Documentation: [Context Configuration with Dynamic Property Sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-dynamic-property-sources)